# xdebug timeout due to windows firewall

Tags: php, windows, xdebug, windows-firewall

We have a problem with xdebug running on a development server when windows clients try to open websites on this server. The server sends an xdebug request to the client which seems to get stuck in the windows firewall if there is no client application (e.g. phpstorm) listening on the xdebug port. This results in a timeout in the browser trying to open a website from the development server.

The problem seems to be the Stealth Mode of the Windows firewall which cannot be disabled and does not send an ICMP Port Unreachable back to the debug server.

The only solution found so far is turning of the firewall completely for the internal domain.

Is there any chance of getting rid of this behavior without having to install special software on any windows client in the network trying to open a website on the development server?

One of the following options would be a good solution for us - but we do not know how to achieve it:

- Having a special php / xdebug configuration for subdomains
- Changing the behavior of the windows firewall on the xdebug port

The following options were discarded due to one reason or the other:

- Installing a client application (e.g. PHPStorm) listening on the corresponding port on every windows client.
- Turning off the windows firewall completely.
- Turning off xdebug completely or requiring special request parameters on each request.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Windows 7, EasyPHP 13.1 Dev server and NetBeans 7.3.1.  When I clicked "debug," my web browser (chrome) would just wait for a page that never came.  I determined that windows firewall was the issue by disconnecting from the internet and then turning off windows firewall.

My solution was to allow more programs through the firewall.  Control Panel -> System and Security -> windows firewall ->allow program or feature through windows firewall.  I added a number of executables just to be safe, but I'm pretty sure it was granting permission for the php executables (php.exe and php-win.exe) that did the trick.